# Shiny dashboard margin between boxes

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I decrease the space between boxes in Shiny dashboard?

I have tried the following:

```
.box-body{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;}
```

But that seems to add a margin towards the inside of the box. What I want is to reduce the space between boxes such that these boxes are basically touching each other.

[image: boxes example]

Comment: You should try this: .box-body{margin:0 !important;}

Comment: Hello there, what you are looking for is to reduce the padding :)

Comment: If you post the link to the site, I would be able to assist you with this in much more detail

Comment: @Rashid you are right about the semicolon (just edited it in the question), but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @KanstantsinArlouski I have tried margin and padding. The .box-body seems to modify a div inside the box, not the box itself. I don't have the dashboard on a server, but it's a straightforward shiny dashboard https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#body

Comment: @CamilaVargasRestrepo Looking into it as we speak.

Answer (score 4):

Use only this CSS:

```
[class*="col-lg-"],[class*="col-md-"],
[class*="col-sm-"],[class*="col-xs-"]{
    padding-right:0 !important;
    padding-left:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the css properties that cause your boxes to be separated the way the are. The col classes are found in bootstrap.css and .box can be found in AdminLTE.min.css.

```
.box { margin-bottom: 0; } 

[class*="col-lg-"],[class*="col-md-"],
[class*="col-sm-"],[class*="col-xs-"]{
  padding-right:0 !important;
  padding-left:0 !important;
}
```